# How to create RDS login that maps to dbo user

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, database-administration

I'm working on migrating a SQL Server database from Azure SQL to AWS RDS, and I am finding some differences in object ownership.

Here's a brief overview of the situation for context:

- Objects (tables, views, schemas) are created by a migration process that runs as a `migration` user with the `db_owner` role.
- The application runs using a different `app` login that has more restricted permissions
- We have several application tables that are created in the `dbo` schema
- We have a `bi` schema that contains several views that select from these `dbo` tables
- There is a `bi` login that maps to a `bi` user in the database which is granted select permission on the `bi` schema (and ideally only from the `bi` schema).

The problem:

- The `bi` schema is created with owner `migration` by the db migrations
- The `dbo` tables are owned by `dbo`, even thought he `migration` user created the tables in that schema - this probably makes sense given that the `dbo` schema is owned by the `dbo` user, but it still seems odd to me that objects created in different schemas by the same user end up being owned by different users.
- When I try to select from a view using the `bi` schema I receive an error that I must grant SELECT permission also to the underlying `dbo` tables, which seems to be due to ownership chaining in SQL Server since the owners of the view and table are different

In our Azure SQL environment, we were able to run the migrations with a login that mapped to the `dbo` user in the db, so that the `bi` views and `dbo` tables were owned by the same user and we did not have to explicitly grant SELECT permission also to `dbo`. I have not yet found a way to map a login in AWS RDS to the `dbo` user - it appears there is a deactivated `rdsa` login that maps to `dbo` but I do not have credentials for this login. RDS only provides a master login / user that does not map to `dbo`.

In the interim, I'm granting the `bi` user SELECT permission to `dbo` as well, but I'm wondering what better options I have in solving this problem. Is there any way to create a login that maps to `dbo`? Do I have to move all the application tables out of the `dbo` schema and into another schema that I can control ownership of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change ownership of all the schemas to DBO.  This will restore all the ownership chains.  Then grant bi select permission on the bi schema. eg

```
alter authorization on schema::bi to dbo
grant select on schema::bi to bi
```

> objects created in different schemas by the same user end up being owned by different users.

objects are always owned by the schema owner by default.  It's possible to change ownership of individual objects to someone else, but it's almost never done, and no one would expect it.  So don't do it.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried `alter authorization on schema::bi to dbo` earlier, but I overlooked needing to also grant select on the `bi` schema again afterwards.

Comment: Actually, I know I had granted this permission earlier when first starting to look into this, but before changing ownership of `bi` to `dbo` - does changing ownership revoke previously granted permissions to the schema, which would have required me to grant select to `bi` again afterwards?